# how to map over an Object and render the arrays inside the object javascript/reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, return

```
const data = {
    "13/11/19": [
    {patientName: "A", room: "room1", user: "k"}, 
    {patientName: "A", room: "room1", user: "k"},
  ], 
    "12/11/19": [
    {patientName: "B", room: "room8", user: "p" }, 
    {patientName: "B", room: "room8", user: "p" },
  ]
}
```

I have got a data object which has 2 arrays. Inside the data object, I have grouped the array by dates. 
In the UI I would like to render a row with the date first`(13/11/19)` then the next rows would be filled with the paitent details `(patientName: A)` until there is another patient with a different date `(12/11/19)`.

If there is a different date and I would want to add a new row with the new date `(12/11/19)` 
then render the patient details`(patientName: B)` until a different date and so on...

I got started with the following function but I haven't gotton any far from here. How can I render a table with date first and the patients array? thanks in advance.

```
Object.keys(data).map(obj => 
  console.log(obj) // gives me the date '13/11/19' & '12/11/19'

  console.log(data[obj].map(p => p)) //gives the both patient A & B

 )
```

```
UI should be 

Row 1 - 13/11/19 
Row 2 - patientName: "A", room: "room1", user: "k" 
Row 3 - patientName: "A", room: "room1", user: "k" 
Row 4 - 12/11/19 
Row 5 - patientName: "B", room: "room8", user: "p" 
Row 6 - patientName: "B", room: "room8", user: "p
```

Comment: So do you want to create six rows, basically?

Comment: Yes @ChrisG 
Row 1 - 13/11/19
Row 2 - patientName: "A", room: "room1", user: "k" 
Row 3 - patientName: "A", room: "room1", user: "k"
   
Row 4 -  12/11/19
Row 5 - patientName: "B", room: "room8", user: "p" 
Row 6 -  patientName: "B", room: "room8", user: "p"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Object.entries(data).map(([date, patients]) => (
  <div key={date}>
    <h1>{date}</h1>
    <ul>
      {patients.map((patient, i) => (<li key={i}>Patient Name: {patient.patientName}</li>)}
    </ul>
  </div>
))
```

Comment: patients.map isn't a function. patients argument is index. this doesn't work

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. I get how it worked. but I didn't realise that you could achieve this with object.entries. specially the (([date, patients])) arguments is a new thing for me.